# Flutter web: How to disable right mouse click for `Draggable` widget activation?

Tags: flutter, widget, mouse, draggable

Now right mouse click activates D&D mode but I don't want it. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found the solution. To disable activation of D&D mode in web you should wrap your `Draggable` with `GestureDetector`:

```
GestureDetector(
  onSecondaryTapDown: (details) {
    // 1. Use empty callback to disable D&D on mouse right button
    // 2. Call `showMenu` to show context menu
  },
  child: Draggable(
    ...
    child: DropTarget(
      ...
    ),
  ),
),
```